# Testing a debounced function in AngularJS with Jasmine never calls the function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, underscore.js, debouncing

I have a method in a service that uses underscore's debounce.

Inside that method is a call to a method on a different service. I'm trying to test that the different service is called.

In my attempts to test the debounced method, the different services' method is never called, and jasmine fails with:

"Expected spy aMethod to have been called."

I know for a fact that it IS called (it logs to console in chrome), it's just called AFTER the expectation already failed.

So... (preferably) without adding Sinon or another dependency and with
bonus points* given to a solution doesn't have to turn the _.debounce into a $timeout...

How do?

```
angular.module('derp', [])
.service('herp', function(){ 
   return {
     aMethod: function(){ 
       console.log('called!'); 
       return 'blown'; 
     }
   }; 
 })
 .service('Whoa', ['herp', function(herp){
   function Whoa(){
     var that = this;
     this.mindStatus = 'meh';
     this.getMind = _.debounce(function(){
       that.mindStatus = herp.aMethod();
     }, 300);
   }
   return Whoa;
 }]);
```

## tests:

```
describe('Whoa', function(){
  var $injector, whoa, herp;

  beforeEach(function(){
    module('derp');
    inject(function(_$injector_){
      var Whoa;
      $injector = _$injector_;
      Whoa = $injector.get('Whoa');
      herp = $injector.get('herp');
      whoa = new Whoa();
    });
  });

  beforeEach(function(){
    spyOn(herp, 'aMethod').andCallThrough();
  });

  it('has a method getMind, that calls herp.aMethod', function(){
    whoa.getMind();
    expect(herp.aMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Why have the AngularJS Testing gods forsaken me?

* I do not know how to give actual bonus points on stackoverflow, but if it is possible, i will.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You just need to mock lodash debounce method:

```
describe('Whoa', function(){
  var $injector, whoa, herp;

  beforeEach(function(){
    module('derp');
    spyOn(_, 'debounce').and.callFake(function(cb) { return function() { cb(); } });
    inject(function(_$injector_){
      var Whoa;
      $injector = _$injector_;
      Whoa = $injector.get('Whoa');
      herp = $injector.get('herp');
      whoa = new Whoa();
    });
  });

  beforeEach(function(){
    spyOn(herp, 'aMethod').andCallThrough();
  });

  it('has a method getMind, that calls herp.aMethod', function(){
    whoa.getMind();
    expect(herp.aMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Nope. Still not working. In both of our cases herp.aMethod IS called, but neither are called before the expectation.

Comment: I wish I had chai as promised right now. an "eventually" would fix this.

Comment: put a break point inside the anonymous function inside the callfake and check the stack to see where it is called from.

Comment: Is the mock function actually getting called?

Comment: no idea why, but i couldn't get your _.debounce to be called. at the end of the day i ended up using [angular debounce](https://github.com/shahata/angular-debounce) so i could use $timeout.flush() in my tests.

Comment: @AndrewLuhring I've edited my answer. I realise now why it didn't work,  the spy was being done after the injector instantiated your service so it was too late. Now, it should work.

Answer (score 3):

Angular `$timeout` has advantage in tests because it is mocked in tests to be synchronous. The one won't have this advantage when third-party asynchronous tools one used. In general asynchronous specs will look like that:

```
var maxDelay = 500;

  ...
  it('has a method getMind, that calls herp.aMethod', function (done){
    whoa.getMind();
    setTimeout(function () {
      expect(herp.aMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
      done();
    }, maxDelay);
  });
```

Since Underscore `debounce` doesn't offer `flush` functionality (while the recent version of Lodash `debounce` [does](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/commit/35c6db12899c116dc2767e699a0855add0891bc7)), asynchronous testing is the best option available.

Answer (score 0):

My debounced function took arguments so I mocked `_.debounce` like this

`spyOn(_, 'debounce').and.callFake(function(cb) {return cb});`

(slight modification on @Wawy's answer)